# Sending authorization headers with jquery and ajax

Tags: jquery, json, authentication, get, xmlhttprequest

I have looked at the following questions here on stackoverflow with no luck in what im trying to do.

[Ajax Authorization Request headers fails again and again](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9820170/ajax-authorization-request-headers-fails-again-and-again)

[jQuery Ajax Unauthorized 401 Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8847748/jquery-ajax-unauthorized-401-error)

[Sending credentials with cross-domain posts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2054316/jquery-sending-credentials-with-cross-domain-posts)

Here is my code that I currently have:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://sample.domain.com/script.php?name1=value1&jsonp=?',
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'json',
            contentType: "application/json",
            beforeSend: function(xhr) {
                 xhr.setRequestHeader("Authentication", "Basic ZnJvbWFwcGx********uOnRoM24zcmQ1UmgzcjM=") //Some characters have been replaced for security but this is a true BASE64 of "username:password"
            },
            success: function(data){
                alert(data);
            }
        });
    });


</script>
```

The subdomain I have is password protected by an .htpasswd file.  The login of the site works just fine for me using the username/password combo used in the base64 encode.

Im running this script on a different domain than the one that the url is on which is why i have the jsonp=? in the url

The response im getting from the console in the browser is:
    `GET http://sample.domain.com/script.php?name1=value1&jsonp=jsonp1334177732136 401 (Authorization Required)`

Comment: Why are you using basic auth here? Your JS will expose the base64'd password to the world, so it won't offer any security. Or have I misunderstood your situation?

Comment: To be honest every method is unsafe via HTTP. That's why HTTPS exists.

Comment: The security here is not the question.  This is just a sample of what I have.  Ive pulled this down to the basic to try and get something to work.  After I have the basic working,  Ill make it secure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JSONP uses a script tag proxy. It wouldn't support custom headers. Are you in control of the endpoint? If so look into enabling CORS, or pass the authentication key in the GET string.

When using jsonp JQuery converts your URL "ajax" request to:

```
<script src="[endpoint]"></script>
```

it then writes a random function

```
var json9409d0sf0d9s0df90 = function() {
     //some callback logic here.
}
```

and appends ?callback=json9409d0sf0d9s0df90

your server then says

```
echo $_GET['callback] . "(" . $json . ")";
```

and sends that back as the response so

```
json9409d0sf0d9s0df90({some: data});
```

is exexcuted by the browser and handled by jQuery's magical handlers that make it respond like a normal ajax callback.

AFAIK, `<script src=""></script>` asset loads wont take custom headers by any standard browser.

Answer (score 7):

The header name is `Authorization`, and you are sending "`Authentication`"

e.g.

> Authorization: Basic QWxhZGRpbjpvcGVuIHNlc2FtBmU=